# Why is it valid to find $C$ in $ \int f(x)dx=g(x)+C$ by plugging in $x=0$?

Tags: integration

Why is it valid to find the value of constant $C$ in $ \int f(x)dx=g(x)+C$ by plugging in a particular value, e.g. $x=0$?

Comment: As given, this doesn't make sense. The value of $C$ can't be "found". Some arbitrary constant must be there in the indefinite integral.

Comment: @user236182 Well that clears it. So the above should be, "C can be found", if $D=\int f(x)dx=g(x)+C$ and by plugging in some $x=x_0$ one shows that $g(x0)+C=D$, i.e. $C=D-g(x_0)$.

Comment: The definition of indefinite integral $\int f(x)\, dx$ is "the collection of all antiderivatives of $f(x)$". All antiderivatives of any function are different by some constant. If you find one antiderivative $g(x)$, then you can write $\int f(x)\, dx=g(x)+C_1$. If you find a different antiderivative $h(x)$, then you can write $\int f(x)\, dx=h(x)+C_2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is **a** primitive of $f$, then

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx=g(b)-g(a)$$

Hence, **the** primitive of $f$ that is zero at $x_0$ is

$$\int_{x_0}^x f(x)dx=g(x)-g(x_0)$$

And you simply add the constant $C=-g(x_0)$ to $g(x)$.